# Sending data encrypted with MCRYPT_3DES as a URL parameter

Tags: php, security, encryption, urlencode

HI,

I am encrypting data with following PHP function:

```
$enc_data = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $_key, $_data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $_iv);
```

If I send the encrypted data per `$_GET` method, it’s not possible to decrypt it back because the `$enc_data` contains `/` and `+` signs:

```
QBlgcQ2+v3wd8RLjhtu07ZBd8aQWjPMfTc/73TPzlyA=
```

Btw. I am using this function to transfer data between .NET 2010 and PHP.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

---

**Solved!**
if someone want to know how to use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query)

```
<?php
echo "<a href='test.php?".http_build_query($enc_data)."'>test</a>";

$_data = str_replace("%3D", "=", $_GET['enc_data']);
$_data = str_replace("%2B", "+", $_GET['enc_data']);
$_data = str_replace("%2F", "/", $_GET['enc_data']);

echo $_data;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) or [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query) to make the encrypted string safe for transmission in a URL.

Comment: hmm i think i can use the http_build_query() for it. I ll put an example code for http_build_query() if someone needs. ty phoenix